# Do objects (like doors) start with a base Defense of 10?

Tags: damage, mutants-and-masterminds-3e, objects

When [Damaging Objects](https://www.d20herosrd.com/9-gamemastering/8-action-adventure/#TOC-DAMAGING-OBJECTS), considered to be Defenseless:

> Inanimate objects are defenseless by definition and therefore subject to finishing attacks (see the [Finishing Attack](https://www.d20herosrd.com/9-gamemastering/8-action-adventure/#TOC-FINISHING-ATTACK) maneuver): essentially, you can choose between making your attack on the object as a routine check or, if you make the attack check normally, gaining an automatic critical hit if your attack hits, for a +5 bonus to effect.

This is all fine and good, except that the last time I had to adjudicate this, with someone trying to kick a door down, they objected to me starting with the Base 10 defense for the door, namely they chose to Power Attack, and were already damage shifted, and completely missed the door. I can kind of see their point that a door shouldn't be that easy to miss hitting. I think I described it as more of a "glancing blow", that they were trying so hard to hit it hard that the blow just skidded off of it. But the question does remain, should a Defenseless object the size of a door start with a defense of 10 such that the average bystander has a little more than a 50/50 chance of actually hitting it if they're trying to hit it hard? Am I reading the rules wrong? Did the player maybe just get a little too greedy in trying to do more damage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> they chose to Power Attack, and were already damage shifted

It sounds like you let them double-dip on the trade-off. A character who is damage-shifted shouldn't be allowed to Power Attack beyond the +5/-5 limit. If you're already damage-shifted, you're essentially *always* power attacking.

Let's say you're PL10, and your attack bonus is +6 and your damage rank is 14. You can power attack for +1 damage / -1 to hit, bringing you up to the +5/-5 limit.

So at worst, you'd have a 25% chance to miss **if you rolled**. However, since a door is defenseless, you can just "take 10" and hit automatically. The only reason to roll is to get that additional +5 damage, giving you a total of +10 damage.

"But that's a 25% chance to miss! It's a DOOR!" Yeah, a door that you're blindly charging at, head tucked down, full speed ahead. You had the option to auto-hit and get +5 damage, but you chose to take a risk of missing to get +10.

Comment: I disagree with you that tradeoffs should limit combat maneuvers, but I agree that there should be some chance to miss in that case. I just don't know if the base defense of 10 is a good place to start for a door. :)

Comment: Well, starting with a base defense of 10 means you have two options:

1) You can auto-hit because it's defenseless. This is essentially "take 10" on the attack roll. So a PC with +10 to hit and rank 10 damage could power attack and still have +5 to hit, which is still an auto-hit. Technically if you allowed a damage-shifted character (+5 to hit and rank 15 damage) to stack power attack, he'd STILL auto-hit (because his +0 to hit still meets the DC 10) and get +10 ranks.

2) You can roll to hit, and if you hit you get +5 damage.

I think the defenseless rules work fine for a door.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider a door (or any Inanimate object, such as something made with the Create power) to have a base defense of 10.  And a dex of -5.  This means most things can be hit on a modified roll of 5 or better.  This does mean it is possible to miss if you have traded off too much accuracy via build and power attack, but it's generally not too hard to hit an inanimate object.  If you are accurate enough, I would let you take ten on the attack and use power attack.